# R dplyr: filter dataframe to get vector of unique values of column

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to get a vector of unique values from filtered dataframe data using `dplyr` library.

Dummy example:

```
df<-data.frame(site =  letters[seq( from = 1, to = 5)],
               year = c(1,2,2,3,4))

  site year
1    a    1
2    b    2
3    c    2
4    d    3
5    e    4
```

I want to print out a vector of `sites` where `year == 2`.

The `dplyr` package returns a `dataframe`. How to turn it to a vector?

```
df %>% 
  filter(year == 2) %>% 
  select(site) #
#  unique ???   how to convert the filtered dataframe to vector?
```

I know how to make this in two steps using classical approach: filter the dataframe and than access the column:

```
# Filter data and get a new dataframe:

df2<-df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(year == 2) %>% 
  select(site)

# Check the column values after filtering:
df2$site
```

But I am sure there is a nicer way in `dplyr`?

Expected output:

```
[1] b c
```

Comment: Use `pull`, `df %>% 
  filter(year == 2) %>%
  pull(site)
`

Comment: Awesome! I could not find this example! Thank you @RonakShah